# NavigationController done button is not showing

Tags: iphone

When i press the infobutton on the mainviewcontroller it shows navbar and uitextview modally but doesn't shows done button.

```
    - (void) modalViewAction:(id)sender     

 self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]autorelease];

[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

 _viewController = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_viewController];

 navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(Done:)] autorelease];

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:self.viewController animated:YES];

[navigationController release];
```

Anyone have ideas why is that Done Button is missing from the navigationcontroller.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added following statement

```
[_viewController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:button animated:YES];
```

to the below code and now Done button is showing on the navigation controller

```
 - (void) modalViewAction:(id)sender

{
self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]autorelease]; 

[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

 _viewController = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_viewController];

UIBarButtonItem * button = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:    UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissView:)] autorelease];

[_viewController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:button animated:YES];

navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:self.viewController animated:YES];

[self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];

[navigationController release];

}
```

So my issue is solved.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Your presenting it Modally:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:self.viewController animated:YES];
```

You need to push it onto the navigation stack:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewControler:self.viewController animated:YES];
```

Now the NavigationController will take care of the back button for you.

Comment: So if i am presenting it modally. There is no other way to show done button. Reason is that i want to use dismissmodalview once i see done button. So that's why i cant use pushviewcontroller

Comment: earlier i tried with push view controller i was not able to dismissview by using poptorootviewcontroller

Comment: Im not sure what you want here. If you have a back button do you still need to pop it manually? If so just use:     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; Which will be just like the user pushed the back button.

Answer (score 1):

You have to either:

1. push the view controller onto the navigation controller (as Hubert
   explained), or
2. create a new UINavigationController and set the
   viewController as the rootViewController of that
   UINavigationController and then you can do:

> [self.navigationController
>   presentModalViewController:newNavigationController animated:YES];